# mozilla addon sdk 1.11 - page-mod cleanup

Tags: mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using page-mod to attach content script to all open tabs !

After that at cretain moment/event i want to remove all attached content scripts from all open tabs!

How can i do that ? .... using already sdk 1.11

```
myPanel.port.on('userlogged', function(rdata) {

    var workers= [];

            function detachWorker(worker, workerArray) {
                var index = workerArray.indexOf(worker);
                if(index != -1) {
                    workerArray.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }


            var pMod = pageMod.PageMod({
                include: "*",
                contentScriptWhen: "end",
                contentScriptFile: data.url("sas_tb.js"),
                attachTo: ["existing", "top", "frame"],
                onAttach: function(worker) {
                    workers.push(worker);
                    worker.on('detach', function () {
                        detachWorker(this, workers);
                    });

                    worker.port.emit('logged', rdata.logged);

                }
            });
});
```

So the contentScriptFile will be attached to all open tabs in the browser, but if i want to ... say logout from my addon how can i remove the contentScriptFile from all attached tabs/workers!?

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly call the Worker's `destroy` method and the SDK will take care of the content scripts